# Does Linux require a user space stack?

Tags: linux-kernel

Is there anything in the Linux kernel that requires a valid user space stack? I.e., if I were to write a program in such a way that it only accesses fixed memory locations in the data segment, or does some computations with registers only, could I safely set the stack pointer to 0 or another invalid address, or even to a valid address without having to fear the memory there to be overwritten?

- I assume hardware interrupts could be handled fine, as they can happen at any time, and the kernel tries hard not to make assumptions about user space's state when handling these.
- What about faulting in a mapped page, though?
- What about making system calls? Not through libc of course, but directly?

Additional question: Does anyone know the answer to this question regarding other operating systems, e.g. MacOS X, the BSDs, Windows?

Comment: Why do you consider a stack such a burden?  *"if I were to write a program ..."* -- Why don't you try writing such a program that is non-trivial to see if that's even possible?  *"I safely set the stack pointer to 0 ..."* -- How do *you* expect to do that unless you hack the kernel?   FYI Many processor architectures and the C language (and other high-level languages) require a stack, so it's not just the Linux OS.  IOW C and Linux are typically used only on processors that have HW stack support.

Comment: @sawdust It's hard to answer all your questions in a comment. I cannot just test it because that doesn't give me a guarantee that what I do is actually allowed; it could just happen to work in my test and break in the next kernel version or architecture. The stack pointer can be trivially changed by `movq $0, %rsp`, no kernel hacking needed. x86 only needs a stack for ISRs, which is irrelevant for user space (of course, you can't push/pop/call/ret). Also, I know about C, but that wasn't my question. I asked whether the _kernel_ requires a valid _user space_ stack at all times.

Comment: To give some more context: I don't necessarily want to avoid the stack completely (though this would be an interesting experiment). I'm thinking of working with very small stacks that have just the right size for the maximum call graph of the current thread/fiber. That means that at times the stack can be completely full, and does not necessarily end on a page boundary. I want to be sure that the kernel can handle such a scenario. Maybe a different way to phrase the question is: Does the Linux kernel require user space to follow a specific ABI?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt anyone can tell you this with much confidence but I'll take a stab.

My guess is that it's technically possible to run with no stack but getting the details right will be very hard.

Interrupts and exceptions (page faults, for example) should save registers to a kernel stack not the user space stack so that's no problem. System calls should even work if coded directly in assembly. (Unless you are running in 32-bit mode and use more than 5 arguments, in which case the sixth is on the user stack, but you could still fix that up that easily enough.)

Debugging will be hard obviously; gdb expects your stack to be arranged just so.

Other things to think about:

Typically you are allocated a stack area at startup. Not sure; you might be able to change that with appropriate linker directives. The stack region is usually configured to grow downward. When there's a page fault at an address not in any currently allocated region, it's assumed that a stack region is to be grown. The faulting address must not be less than the value of `sp` (i.e. `esp/rsp`) (less a 64K fudge). I guess that's not a problem if you're not using a stack.

When you call the `clone` syscall to create a new task (thread), you provide a stack pointer for the new task. I'm not sure what exactly the kernel does with that, looks like it just stuffs into the `sp` register in the new task (if it's non-zero). Which leads me to...

The `clone` syscall and a number of others are not well-specified. There's a lot of magic embedded in libc to properly handle `fork`, `pthread_create` and so forth. You'll have to know that magic and implement it yourself if you want to create additional threads.

Signal handling expects to be able to push arguments onto the user space stack. I don't think you could use signals without a stack -- or at least it would be very complicated.

Comment: So it looks like I'm just going to need to have faith in the kernel not doing something unexpected. At least Linux has a policy of never breaking user space. Thanks for reminding me about the special treatment of `clone()` and friends, that's something I'm going to have to watch out for. For signal handlers, it's possible to set an alternate stack with `sigaltstack(2)`.